# HA-Proxy balancing by source doesnt appear consistent

Tags: sticky, haproxy

Using HA-Proxy 1.4.18 I am using **balance source** as the option to balance a tcp stream to 2 servers. However from an admittedly very small sample set of connections it appears that they all just go to the one server - the server listed first in the haproxy config.

- listen videos *:1935
- balance source
- mode tcp
- server  server1 192.168.0.1:1935
- server  server2 192.168.0.2:1935

I have not seen it split the load onto the 2 boxes. This does work when I use balance roundrobin however for this particular application I cannot use this method.

Any ideas for an otherwise persistent session loadbalanced between these 2 machines from the clients?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you test the balance ?, the doc says :

> The source IP address is hashed and divided by the total
>   weight of the running servers to designate which server will
>   receive the request. This ensures that the same client IP
>   address will always reach the same server as long as no
>   server goes down or up. If the hash result changes due to the
>   number of running servers changing, many clients will be
>   directed to a different server. This algorithm is generally
>   used in TCP mode where no cookie may be inserted. It may also
>   be used on the Internet to provide a best-effort stickiness
>   to clients which refuse session cookies. This algorithm is
>   static by default, which means that changing a server's
>   weight on the fly will have no effect, but this can be
>   changed using "hash-type"

If you tested with just 2 different IP source you maybe fall in a particular case.

Comment: Cheers Rodolphe. The sampe set was just too small. It did even out quite well after more clients were added.